# Ruby when to use methods ! vs assigning the value back

Tags: ruby

While working in Ruby I often find myself in a conflict between using methods with a `!` or using a normal method as assign the value back.  I am not sure when to use what.
For example,
I have 2 hashes (h1 and h2) and I want to merge them and store the value back in hash h1, now should I be using 
`h1.merge!(h2)`
or
`h1 = h1.merge(h2)`?

Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: I prefer to avoid side-effects (sometimes denoted with `!`) in most cases. *I find that reducing side-effects (in any language) usually makes code easier to reason about* - and can help to avoid some subtle unexpected interactions. I find string side-effects (`gsub!` etc) especially problematic to deal with, in part because many common "modern" languages do not have mutable strings like Ruby. (Of course there are plenty of non-`!` methods that also cause side-effects .. and Ruby does not try to be "pure" by any means.)

Answer (score 7):

Most of the time there is very little difference between `h1.merge!(h2)` and `h1 = h1.merge(h2)`.

However, note that:

Since `merge!` modifies the old hash, you might be unintentionally affecting some other object in your program that holds a reference to that same hash.  It is bad practice to modify a hash that you received as a method parameter because the caller usually does not expect it.

Using `merge!` is not functional programming, if you are a fan of that.

Using `merge!` is probably more efficient since it does not create a new hash, especially for large hashes.

I would use `merge` most of the time and only use `merge!` if I determine that it is safe and better.

Comment: +1 for thinking in a larger scale than the given use case. It's important not to breaks with other programmers expectations

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any difference between the two?

Yes,of-course there is.

You should use `!`(bang) version of [**`Hash#merge`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge),when you want to change the receiver itself.

**Example**

```
h1 = {a: 1}
h2 = {b: 2}
h3 = h1.merge(h2) # => {:a=>1, :b=>2}
h1 # => {:a=>1}
```

Now see :

```
h1 = {a: 1}
h2 = {b: 2}
h1.merge!(h2) # => {:a=>1, :b=>2}
h1 # => {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

> h1 = h1.merge(h2) gives the same answer

Humm,that is because,you are assinging the new hash to `h1` after applying the `Hash#merge` method:

```
h1 = {a: 1}
h2 = {b: 2}
h1.object_id # => 69435570
h1 = h1.merge(h2) # => {:a=>1, :b=>2}
h1 # => {:a=>1, :b=>2}
h1.object_id # => 69434820
```

As you said *I want to merge them and store the value back in hash h1*,Then I would recommend to use [**`Hash#merge!`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21).Because `h1 = h1.merge(h2)` is same as `h1.merge!(h2)`(will save the new hash creation,and assign back it to the `h1`).

Comment: h1 = h1.merge(h2) gives the same answer

Answer (score 2):

> While working in Ruby I often find myself in a conflict between using
>   methods with a ! or using a normal method.

You should be thinking about more important things, so just adopt the rule: I will never use bang methods. Now be free and soar...

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 1_000_000

h1 = {a: 1, b: 2}
h2 = {b: 3, c: 4}

Benchmark.bm(20) do |b|
  b.report("no-bang-hash-merge") do
    n.times { h1 = h1.merge h2 }
  end

  b.report("bang-hash-merge") do
    n.times { h1.merge! h2 }
  end
end

--output:--
                          user     system      total        real
no-bang-hash-merge     2.750000   0.050000   2.800000 (  2.817345)
bang-hash-merge        0.400000   0.000000   0.400000 (  0.406870)
```

.

```
require 'benchmark'

hash_size = 10_000

#Keys overlap:
key1 = 'a'
key2 = nil

h1 = {}
hash_size.times do |i|
  h1[key1] = i
  key2 = key1.dup if i == hash_size/2
  key1.succ!
end


h2 = {}
hash_size.times do |i|
  h2[key2] = i
  key2.succ!
end

=begin
#No overlap:
key = 'a'

h1 = {}
hash_size.times do |i|
  h1[key] = i
  key.succ!
end


h2 = {}
hash_size.times do |i|
  h2[key] = i
  key.succ!
end
=end

n = 100_000

puts "50% of keys overlap, hash size #{hash_size}:"
Benchmark.bm(20) do |b|
  b.report("no-bang-hash-merge") do
    n.times { h1 = h1.merge h2 }
  end

  b.report("bang-hash-merge") do
    n.times { h1.merge! h2 }
  end
end

--some test runs:---

50% of keys overlap, hash size 10000:
                           user     system      total        real
no-bang-hash-merge   1500.570000  74.520000 1575.090000 (1695.523240)
bang-hash-merge      255.910000   0.940000 256.850000 (269.957178)



No keys overlap, hash size 10000:
                           user     system      total        real
no-bang-hash-merge   1906.070000 109.340000 2015.410000 (2151.865636)
bang-hash-merge      162.680000   0.190000 162.870000 (163.369607)
```

So if you need the speed, bang away.  Otherwise, don't risk it.

Comment: One test like that doesn't mean much because the size of the hash and the number of overlapping keys could alter the results.  I'm running some additional tests now and I will post the results.

Comment: sure I am waiting to see those.. :)